# Access foreground data from background process

Tags: shell-script, background-process

I want to run a process in the background, using `&`,
and have the process access the data used in the foreground process.

Here is an example:

```
A() {
  echo "$a"
}
a="abc"
while true; do echo "$(A)"; sleep 10; done &
a="xyz"
```

The output from the background process is always "abc". It does not matter what value is placed in `a` after the background task is started. In the example, I want the first iteration to output "abc",
and 10 seconds later the output should be "xyz".

I want to have a background process to behave like a thread in Windows. The thread has full access to all data (but must not change data that would affect the UI). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is simply to use files. 
Other approaches include named pipes and (in some shells) coprocesses.

Comment: My preference is to have the code in the process be the same whether is it run in the foreground or background. That is how a windows Thread works for the most part. Is this not possible? If not, are you saying that I must pass data between background and foreground code using channels like a file on disk, or a named pipe?

Comment: I’m not sure what the first sentence of your comment means.  ``A() { cat a_file; }`` will work the same in foreground and background.  And yes, foreground and background processes are not only separate processes, but separate process *groups*, so, yes, I’m saying that you can’t easily share memory between them.